Using OpenTelemetry to remote write to localhost
I'm trying to use OpenTelemetry to export metrics to a remote endpoint. As a test, I'm trying to export a counter to a Prometheus server at localhost:8000. However, when I run the below code, I can't see the metrics at localhost:8000/metrics. Could anyone point me to where I'm getting this wrong? Note that I am using opentelemetry-exporter-prometheus-remote-write to try to accomplish this.
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
import random
import time
from opentelemetry import metrics
from opentelemetry.exporter.prometheus_remote_write import PrometheusRemoteWriteMetricsExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics import MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export import PeriodicExportingMetricReader


start_http_server(8000, addr='localhost')
exporter = PrometheusRemoteWriteMetricsExporter(endpoint='http://localhost:8000', headers={})
reader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(exporter, 1000)
provider = MeterProvider(metric_readers=[reader])
metrics.set_meter_provider(provider)
meter = metrics.get_meter(__name__)
requests_counter = meter.create_counter('test_counter', 'Random counter')

while True:
    num = random.randint(0, 50)
    print(num)
    requests_counter.add(num, {'env': 'staging', 'label': '9999'})
    time.sleep(1)

EDIT: Here's some revised code after running
docker run \
[prom image] \
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
--enable-feature=remote-writer-receiver

Unfortunately still not working.
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
import random
import time
from opentelemetry import metrics
from opentelemetry.exporter.prometheus_remote_write import PrometheusRemoteWriteMetricsExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics import MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export import PeriodicExportingMetricReader


# start_http_server(8000, addr='localhost')
exporter = PrometheusRemoteWriteMetricsExporter(endpoint='http://localhost:9090/api/v1/write', headers={})
reader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(exporter, 1000)
provider = MeterProvider(metric_readers=[reader])
metrics.set_meter_provider(provider)
meter = metrics.get_meter('my_meter')
requests_counter = meter.create_counter(name='test_counter', description='Random counter', unit='1')

while True:
    num = random.randint(0, 50)
    print(num)
    requests_counter.add(num)
    time.sleep(1)


A couple of things (see Storage: Overview):

You must enable Prometheus to access remote writes
The endpoint should be /api/v1/write

NB You may want to call
meter.create_counter(
    name='test_counter',
    description='Random counter',
)

podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=9090:9090/tcp \
docker.io/prom/prometheus:v2.54.1 \
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
--enable-feature=remote-write-receiver

NB The default Prometheus Web endpoint port is 9090.
Then, after running your (revised) code, I can query the Prometheus API:
curl \
--silent \
--get \
--data-urlencode "query=test_counter[15s]" \
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query \
| jq -r .

{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "test_counter",
          "env": "staging",
          "label": "9999",
          "service_name": "unknown_service",
          "telemetry_sdk_language": "python",
          "telemetry_sdk_name": "opentelemetry",
          "telemetry_sdk_version": "1.27.0"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1726765795.586,
            "344"
          ],
          [
            1726765796.598,
            "374"
          ],
          [
            1726765797.605,
            "383"
          ],
          [
            1726765798.611,
            "409"
          ],
          [
            1726765799.616,
            "419"
          ],
          [
            1726765800.623,
            "460"
          ],
          [
            1726765801.633,
            "476"
          ],
          [
            1726765802.641,
            "502"
          ],
          [
            1726765803.648,
            "523"
          ],
          [
            1726765804.652,
            "548"
          ],
          [
            1726765805.66,
            "592"
          ],
          [
            1726765806.666,
            "619"
          ],
          [
            1726765807.672,
            "668"
          ],
          [
            1726765808.679,
            "674"
          ],
          [
            1726765809.687,
            "709"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


Tyvm for the fast response! I've posted my updated code above along with the command i ran for docker. I'm getting a "Export POST request failed with reason: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://localhost:9090/api/v1/write" error. I am able to pull up prometheus at localhost:9090 and can see requests tracker for localhost:9090/api/v1/write at /metrics. When I run your curl command, i get {"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[]}}. Any idea what could be causing this error? Feel like it's close :)

Is your Python code running on the same host? Is it running in a container? Since I'm unable to repro your issue, it's challenging to debug. Please add any salient information.

Running from pycharm IDE

PyCharm on the same host where Prometheus is running?

pycharm is running on my desktop (i assume that's the same host?) and the docker container is running on my desktop at localhost:9090. Sorry if I'm not being helpful - i'm a self-taught coder and don't always know terminology

I just reran everything again and i'm getting 204 errors against /api/v1/write every time my code tries to write to the container

OK, finally got this working. A few things i didn't understand: 1) a random number could get appended to your metric name (i had to query "test_counter_1" instead of "test_counter". 2) metrics that are written from remote don't show up in the /metrics endpoint output of the target prometheus server. TYVM for the help!!!!

Ah, I didn't realize the metric renaming could occur either. The only metrics you'll see on the server's /metrics endpoint are the metrics that its exporting. This is why you'll see the server configured to scrape itself under targets.
